# Python functional abstraction

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

Hi, guys, im very new to python. I was tasked to do such a question but I have no idea what went wrong with what I've written down. Can any1 please enlighten me

Comment: Please paste your code here instead of posing a screenshot

Comment: i typed sth like this :
def greet(name, language):
   if language =="English":
       greet = "Nice to meet you"
    elif language =="Klingon":
           greet = "nuqneH"
    elif language =="Elvish":
               greet ="Gi suilon"
    return greet + name
    greet('Ben', 'English')

Comment: greet('Ben', 'English') is in the greet function. And your identation is all over the place.

Comment: how do i execute it to become  Nice to meet you Ben? do i actually print?

Comment: It's clear from your question and your follow-up comments that you do not understand the very basics of programming.  I would suggest you find a better tutorial at [Python for Non-Programmers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers).

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
def greet(name, language):
    if language=="English":
        greet="Nice to meet you"
    else:
        greet="unknown language"
    return greet+ " " + name


greet("Ben", "English")
```

I'm sure you can fill in the rest. Pay attention to the indentation(the number of spaces from the left hand margin). 4 spaces per level.

Answer (score 1):

Do try this out:

```
def greet(name, language):
  if language == "English":
    return f"Nice to meet you {name}"
  elif language == "Elvish":
    return f"Gi suilon {name}"
  elif language == "Klingon":
    return f"nuqneH {name}"
```

You cannot use print statement to print out the string but instead must use return statement. Since, you need to have the name argument needed for the greeting, we have to use a formatted string.

Answer (score -1):

Your call to the greet function is indented. It should not be indented (the last line)

Comment: i dont really get what does indented mean . im a beginner. do u mind correcting for me?

Comment: The last line should be aligned all the way to the left (it should align with the def), and should be:

print greet('Ben', 'English')

Comment: its not correct when i submit it. btw, the question says Note: Do not use the command print to print the greeting, greet should be return a string. what does this mean?

Comment: Oh, ok I see. So look at Daniel's answer. In your return statement you need to add a space, otherwise the greeting and name gets squished together. So leave everything as you have it in your answer and just change your return statement to this: return greeting + " " + name

Comment: I noticed one other thing. Look at the indentation between line 3 and line 5. When you see the indentation getting larger, that means the editor has found some syntax error. You should stop there and figure out why. In your case, you added an extra space in line 5. The elif should align perfectly with if (it doesn't), and that causes the incorrect indentation. By the way, if you want learn Python, you need to learn Python specific vocabulary, such as "indented". It's not just English, it's a Python-specific terminology as well!